# URL Authentication Not Working on Apcahe2.4 version with Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, connect-modrewrite, urlauthenticationchallenges

Apache 2.4 Version configuration file is enabled with "mod_rewrite" module.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Authentication Modules Loaded and shared the output for the command : apachectl -M | grep 'auth'

```
auth_basic_module (shared)
auth_digest_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authn_anon_module (shared)
authn_dbm_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authz_owner_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_dbm_module (shared)
authnz_ldap_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
```

In apache2.4 - Web Server configuration file for the Application directory

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/logfile>
 AllowOverride AuthConfig
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

.htaccess file placed under the logfile directory

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/home/ec2-user/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
Require user tom
```

Accessing the logfile via url , it must ask the url authentication , after the successful validation it will allow to view the file.

But it will generate the **500 - Internal server Error** and sharing the apache server log

***.htaccess: Invalid command 'AuthType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration***

Answer (score 0):

The below modules need to be enabled on Apache 2.4 for url authentication

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

Other Support modules - Authenticaiton related

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
```